# scikit-learn FeatureUnion with Pytorch

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pytorch

Suppose that I have a neural network written in Pytorch that act as some kind of features extractor and I wrap it in 2 slightly different Scikit-learn transformers so that they can extract different feature. Schematically, the code looks like this:

```
net = SomePytorchModule()
transformer_1 = Transformer1(net)
transformer_2 = Transformet2(net)
```

So basically, the 2 transformers are sharing the same neural net but using it in a different way. Now, I want to put them into `FeatureUnion`

```
union = FeatureUnion([
            ('transformer_1': transformer_1),
            ('transformer_2': transformer_2)])
```

It works fine so far. But suppose I want to do a parallel job, that is:

```
union = FeatureUnion([
            ('transformer_1': transformer_1),
            ('transformer_2': transformer_2)],
        n_jobs = 2)
```

How can I make sure that the two processes share the same `net` so that no copy is required because the neural network is quite large